# How to escape json slurper processing the variable type values in response

Tags: json, groovy, groovyshell

I have a json response like below

```
{ events": [
      {
      "documentService":       {
          "key": null,
         "wsdlLocation": "${ATOKEN}://${BTOKEN}:${CTOKEN}/somesrc/ItemServiceV2?WSDL",
         
      },
      "documentTransform": null
     
   }
] 
}
```

and I have the below groovy script

parseText( response ) here response is above json
The main aim of the script is just to list the wsdlLocation in the response

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = jsonSlurper.parseText( response ) 

def eventsList= parsedJson.get("events")

def noOfeventnoWsdl =0;
def noOfeventyesWsdl =0;
for( def ievent: eventsList){
    if(ievent.documentService != null){
        noOfeventyesWsdl++
        log.info ievent.documentService.wsdlLocation.toString()
    }else{
        noOfeventnoWsdl++
    }
}
```

and execution of the result is

==> INFO:://:/somesrc/ItemServiceV2?WSDL

instead

==> INFO:: ${ATOKEN}://${BTOKEN}:${CTOKEN}/somesrc/ItemServiceV2?WSDL
or
whereas

ATOKEN is https

BTOKEN is hostname

CTOKEN is port

I am also ok with the below out put

==> INFO:: https://somehost:1234/somesrc/ItemServiceV2?WSDL

I just want the output either without expanding the parameter
or if there is a way to inject the ATOKEN, BTOKEN,CTOCKEN in jsonSlurper context that is also fine.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonSlurper` doesn't substitute or evaluate the dollar sign expressions.  So I'm left to assume that the JSON string you have is defined in the source file, and what you're experiencing is `GString` substitution expressions.  If you wish to leave the `${expression}` within the Json text you'll want to escape the dollar sign like so:

```
"wsdlLocation": "\${ATOKEN}://\${BTOKEN}:\${CTOKEN}/somesrc/ItemServiceV2?WSDL",
```

The other option is to extract that out of the source files so it won't be evaluated as a `GString`, and move it to a proper file:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file/example.json")
def json = new JsonSlurper().parse( file )
```

If you do the above you don't need to escape the `${}` expressions in your json.